# Searching for closest entry in a table

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

I have a large table of triplets whose structure is:

```
list=Table[{a,b, RandomReal[]}, {a,1,100}, {b,1,100}]
```

I would like to search through the list by looking for the closest entry labeled by `{a,b}` to a given input `{x,y}` and return the associated third item in the triplet. To give an example, if I have

```
{x, y} = {10.2, 5.1}
```

I would like to return the triplet

```
{10, 5, c}
```

Where `c` is the associated random real in the table.
I have tried using `Nearest`, but the structure of the table does not seem compatible with search.

Comment: Hi, I tried to improve the formatting:  To format code blocks, you have to surround them with blank lines, in addition to indenting.  Inline code is enclosed in backticks.  You can look at the edits to see. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]; (* for reproducibility; omit in application *)

list = Table[N@{a, b, RandomReal[]}, {a, 1, 100}, {b, 1, 100}];
flat = Flatten[list, 1];

nf = Nearest[flat[[All, 1 ;; 2]] -> flat]
(*
   NearestFunction[{10000, 2}, <>]
*)

nf[{10.2, 5.1}]
(*
   {{10., 5., 0.588169}}
*)
```

Note: I converted the OP's integer coordinates to `Real` with `N`, so that `list` and `flat` would be [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) for efficiency, in case the table gets much bigger.  It doesn't really make a difference on the OP's example.  Omit the `N` if desired.

Comment: Could you clarify how function nf works? I see what you are doing with Flatten but I don't understand how nf processes its argument.

Comment: @Whelp  It's the third synopsis on the documentation page.  Think of the rule (`->`) as mapping the LHS -> RHS (element by element).  `Nearest` will find the nearest element in the LHS and return the corresponding element of the RHS.